# How can I perform multiple comparison for paired sample t-test?

Tags: t-test, spss, multiple-comparisons

I want to compare data using paired sample t-test for several cases.
The several cases are independant.
At first, I did paired sample t-test several times.
But, others agued that I have to perform multiple comparison because of type 1 error.
I tried to find the method to solve it. 
It seems that I have to use ANOVA.
But, I connot understand how can I perform it because the explanation is too simple.
I use SPSS for statical test.
Whould you explain how can I perform multiple comparison for paired sample t-test using SPSS?
What should be used for Fixed Factor and Dependent Variables?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion in the comments, my original assumptions about the problem were wrong. The setup is that there are ten groups measured before and after (something like that), making for ten paired tests. My suggestion was then to test each group for a mean significantly different from zero. Because there are ten tests, it would then be appropriate to make some kind of adjustment for multiple testing. While Bonferroni has its flaws, it's a simple procedure and allows us to say that, if we want to test at $\alpha=0.05$, we should only consider tests to show significant differences from zero if their p-values are $\le 0.05/10 = 0.005$.

**(ORIGINAL POST DOWN BELOW)**

I will assume that you have some group of subjects and measure them a couple of times. You want to compare some value (say mean) at all of those times.

Let's say you measure subjects in January, February, March, and April. You then want to compare how they perform each subsequent month after the initial measurements in January, so you wind up with the difference in measurement for each subject from January to February, January to March, and January to April.

You know how to do each of those paired t-tests, right? Do them!

However, you're doing three of them, so if you test at $\alpha=0.05$, you have three opportunities to make a type I error and reject a null hypothesis that is true. You then would put some further restrictions on the p-value, perhaps using something called the Bonferroni adjustment. For Bonferroni, since you are performing three tests, you require the p-value to be a third as small as usual, so if you're testing at $\alpha=0.05$, you require $p \le 0.05/3 \approx 0.167$ to consider any of the three tests to show a significant difference. That is, if your p-values are $0.03$, $0.02$, and $0.04$, even though all are below $0.05$, you do not reject the null hypothesis for any of the three.

There are better techniques than Bonferroni, but it's a start.

I think that gets at what you want to do, but please do comment if I'm not addressing your situation, and we'll work to determine and then answer your question.

Comment: Thank you Dave for your comment. It is right. But I need the method to perform it on SPSS. My data is not a repeaed measurement data. I measured brain signals in two situation on 10 sites.I want to compare the two situation data for 10 sites. Therefore, "Repeated Measures" may be not proper. Could you explain how can I perform it using SPSS? Thank you.

Comment: @HongGiYeom If you just had one brain site, would you know how to do it? I think you're right that you don't have repeated measures, but it sounds like your situation is that you have 10 groups that you measure in January and then again in February, and you want to compare the changes. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, your explaination is correct. I used the "paired sample t-test" for one group (one brain site). Do you know how can I apply this method to 10 group (considering multiple comparison)?

Comment: @HongGiYeom Are you just curious which groups are different from zero or which groups are different from each other? That will affect how many comparisons you do.

Comment: Thank you Dave for continuous reply. I am not interested in group comparison. I want to find the group that have different measurement between January and February.

Comment: Then you'll just do ten paired t-tests with some kind of adjustment for doing multiple comparisons. My suggestion is to go with Bonferroni until you're comfortable enough with this idea to do more advanced techniques. So you would only consider a difference significant if it has a p-value of 0.005 or lower, rather than 0.05 (assuming you want to test at the 0.05-level).

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. I tried to apply another correction method such as Tukey or Duncan because the Bonferroni apply the over correction (too low p-value). But it seems that your suggestion is best. Thank you very much. I hope you have good days.